# eCommerce website - taking payments and Stripe

Tags: e-commerce, stripe-payments

I'm considering setting up a eCommerce website and was wondering about the payment side of things.

After some searching I came across Stripe, which seems very similar to PayPal and Google Checkout.

I have a few questions about Stripe and eCommerce in general.

1. What do I need to take payments on my website? Presume that I have the shop set up, and the buy button in place. Do I need an SSL certificate, I've read something about being PCI complaint? What is and why would I need a merchant account.
2. Stripe appears to handle a number of things for me, and it stores the users card details. How would this work with things such as logging in to a website. Would I store the users email and password and then when they wanted to buy something Stripe would just handle the credit card side of things or would the entire user details be stored on Stripe.
3. Can you build and style your own payment form that then connects to Stripe or do you have to use their form on your page?
4. Do you have to upload all of your products to Stripe or can you store these in your own database and just pass the value of goods purchased to Stripe for payment?
5. What are the advantages/disadvantages of Stripe and is there any competitors that I should know about?

Comment: 1. Yes you need SSL certificate for your domain. - 2. All data are stored by Stripe. - 3. EasyPie uses Stripe Payment Element. - 4. You can add your products on your Stripe Dashboard. - 5. Checkout details on https://easypie.shop/

Answer (score 0):

1. Stripe requests that you should serve up payments pages over SSL. Anyone involved in payment processing must comply with PCI, if you use something like Stripe you will need to serve the payments page on SSL, but Strip will handle the payment info. Check out https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do for more details on what you'd need to do.
2. Not entirely sure on this front, perhaps someone else can comment?
3. You'll be able to style your page and use Stripe for the payment piece.
4. You can use Stripe's checkout or build your own (sounds like this is what you want to do) via Stripe.js.
5. Stripe is generally recognized as one of the most developer-friendly ways to accept payments online. They've worked hard to build a simple service that a developer can get up and running a matter of hours. Braintree is a competitor that may offer some valued added services and you might want to take a look at Balanced as well. I work at LevelUp, which has been used in conjunction with Stripe (as another payment method, similar to PayPal) and as a stand alone solution for apps processing online or mobile payments.